# How do I add/open a 3rd-party Android APK file to/with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, apk

So far after much investigation, I got as far as finding `Tools->Archive Manager` in Visual Studio 2017; however, I have no idea where to put archives to be viewed in this manager.

Other than `Current Solution` there is an `All Archives` menu on the left side, which looks like a `Global` repository, but I cannot seems to add anything to it.

Drag-n-drop does nothing either. I even tried creating a new Android project and dropping the .apk files into the bin folder and still nothing, so I'm at a loss.

Is it not possible to open 3rd-party APK files in Visual Studio (the ones I have are unsigned) in order to sign and test it in the emulator?

Comment: No it is not. If you want to sign/test an apk, directly use the Android SDK cmd line tools.

Comment: Why not use [keytool](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually) to sign your apk, and use [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html?) to install and test the apk on your emulator？

Comment: Why bother with the command line when I can easily use Android Studio? lol The question was checking if I can do it via the Visual Studio IDE, and if not, the answer would be "No".  I have no objections doing it another way.